# Behaviour of vTaskDelayUntil in FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos

The documentation of `vTaskDelayUntil` says that the reference argument will be updated, but it's not clear to me what it will be updated to.

For example, assuming one tick is one ms, if I have

```
     TickType_t xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount() ;
     // Assume xLastWakeTime is 0
     /// Do something that takes 25 ms
     vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, 10 );
     // Wake at 25, xLastWakeTime is 10 or 25
     /// Do something that takes 1 ms
     vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, 10 );
     // Wake at 26 or 35, xLastWakeTime is 20 or 35
     /// Do something that takes 1 ms
     vTaskDelayUntil( &xLastWakeTime, 10 );
     // Wake at 30 or 45?
```

how much time should this take?  I can see a case for 30ms or 45ms.  It depends on whether the first call increments `xLastWakeTime` by 25 or by 10.